# Not able to spawn basic shapes in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial on rviz [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A Basic Shapes)

But i am not able to correct the TF global issue as in the screenshot.
[image: rviz]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223579/not-able-to-spawn-basic-shapes-in-rviz/) by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2016-01-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CHIN](https://answers.ros.org/users/35553/chin/) on 2021-11-02**:
I tried changing the rviz 'Global Options' 'Fixed Frame' to my_frame. but nothing happened. I tried to run the command below too, but nothing changed too

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 /map /my_frame 10
```

the terminal doesn't show any other error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing the rviz  'Global Options' 'Fixed Frame' to my_frame.

In the tutorial you are sending the markers position in the frame my_frame, but rviz is set to display map, and if you have not set any transforms to connect the frame map to my_frame  rviz can't calculate the markers position in the map frame.

And you need to add a markers display to rviz (maybe you have already done this, but i can't see it in your  screenshot).
Just follow the Tutorials Point '5. Viewing the Markers'.

To change the Fixed Frame:
Open rviz, klick on map (on the text next to Fixed Frame) and just type the new frame name my_frame.
I thought i could choose the frame from a list, but i just built the tutorial program and tried it, but i had to type the name my_frame.

Rviz is often hiding (or it is not recognizable) that you can edit a parameter like Fixed Frame.

I think you are trying to change the Fixed Frame in Global Status, where you get the warning message. Try changing the Fixed Frame under Global Options.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-01-06**:
Marker Status is OK. Marker Topic is `visualization_marker` . But I don't understand how to modify Global Status-Fixed Frame to my_frame.

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-01-06**:
As soon as i type `my_frame` and press enter, the text goes back to `No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist`

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-01-06**:
Thanks a lot!